# Why processing a view takes longer than processing a table, in SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, view, ssas, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I have a SSAS cube that one of its data sources is from a view having numerous rows derived from multiple joins and groupings.

When I process my cube with that view, its takes too long to complete (about one hour). But when I insert the resultset of the view in a temp table (it takes 6 seconds in sql server) and read the cube's data from that table, it will be done quickly about 3 minutes.

1) The main question is why this happens? What is the SQL Server mechanisms for reading a view in SSAS?

2) The second question: How can I solve this problem?

**Update:**

I found the **SSAS generated query** that takes long time from profiler:

```
SELECT [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsQty0_0]        AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsQty0_0],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsQtyConfirmed0_1]       AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsQtyConfirmed0_1],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsAmountPrice0_2]        AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsAmountPrice0_2],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsAmountUserPrice0_3]        AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsAmountUserPrice0_3],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsAmountCost0_4]     AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsAmountCost0_4],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsRespiteDays0_5]        AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsRespiteDays0_5],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsQty_BackSale0_6]       AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsQty_BackSale0_6],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails0_7]       AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails0_7],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8]     AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsinvProductID0_9]       AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsinvProductID0_9],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_2].[CreateDate]     AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentsCreateDate9_0],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_3].[ExecDate]       AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentsExecDate11_0],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_5].[hrsEmployeeID_Visitor]      AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentshrsEmployeeID_Visitor13_0],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_5].[totCostCenterID]        AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentstotCostCenterID13_1],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_6].[saleChannelID]      AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentssaleChannelID15_0],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_7].[scuCmpyDurID]       AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentsscuCmpyDurID17_0],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_8].[invOperationID]     AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentsinvOperationID19_0],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_9].[totMergedPersonID]      AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentstotMergedPersonID21_0],
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_10].[saleDocumentTypeID]        AS 
       [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentssaleDocumentTypeID23_0]
FROM   (
           SELECT [Qty]              AS [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsQty0_0],
                  [QtyConfirmed]     AS 
                  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsQtyConfirmed0_1],
                  [AmountPrice]      AS 
                  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsAmountPrice0_2],
                  [AmountUserPrice]  AS 
                  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsAmountUserPrice0_3],
                  [AmountCost]       AS 
                  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsAmountCost0_4],
                  [RespiteDays]      AS 
                  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsRespiteDays0_5],
                  [Qty_BackSale]     AS 
                  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsQty_BackSale0_6],
                  1                  AS [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails0_7],
                  [DocumentID]       AS 
                  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8],
                  [invProductID]     AS 
                  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsinvProductID0_9]
           FROM   (
                      SELECT ID,
                             DocumentID,
                             invProductID,
                             Qty,
                             QtyConfirmed,
                             AmountPrice,
                             AmountUserPrice,
                             AmountCost,
                             RespiteDays,
                             Date_UpdateLast,
                             Qty_BackSale
                      FROM   biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails
                  )                  AS [biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails]
       )                                AS  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails],
       [dbo].[biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments]  AS  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_2],
       [dbo].[biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments]  AS  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_3],
       [dbo].[biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments]  AS  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_5],
       [dbo].[biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments]  AS  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_6],
       [dbo].[biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments]  AS  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_7],
       [dbo].[biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments]  AS  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_8],
       [dbo].[biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments]  AS  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_9],
       [dbo].[biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments]  AS  [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_10]
WHERE  (
           (
               [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8] 
               = [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_2].[ID]
           )
           AND (
                   [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8] 
                   = [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_3].[ID]
               )
           AND (
                   [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8] 
                   = [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_5].[ID]
               )
           AND (
                   [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8] 
                   = [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_6].[ID]
               )
           AND (
                   [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8] 
                   = [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_7].[ID]
               )
           AND (
                   [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8] 
                   = [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_8].[ID]
           )
           AND (
                   [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8] 
                   = [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_9].[ID]
               )
           AND (
                   [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails].[dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetailsDocumentID0_8] 
                   = [dbo_biVW_Fact_SaleDocuments_10].[ID]
               )
       )
```

My view is `biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails`

and its content is(**Content Query**):

```
SELECT        dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.DocumentID, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.invProductID, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Qty, 
                         dbo.saleDocumentDetails.QtyConfirmed, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountPrice, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountUserPrice, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountCost, 
                         dbo.saleDocumentDetails.RespiteDays, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Date_UpdateLast, SUM(idd.Qty) AS Qty_BackSale
FROM            dbo.saleDocuments INNER JOIN
                         dbo.saleDocumentDetails ON dbo.saleDocuments.ID = dbo.saleDocumentDetails.DocumentID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Dim_Dates AS dd ON dbo.saleDocuments.CreateDate = dd.ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Dim_Dates AS dd2 ON dbo.saleDocuments.ExecDate = dd2.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.invDocumentDetails AS idd ON dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID = idd.saleDocumentDetailID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.invDocuments AS id2 ON id2.ID = idd.invDocumentID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.invOperations AS io1 ON io1.ID = id2.invOperationID AND io1.Code = '33'
WHERE        (dbo.saleDocuments.hrsEmployeeID_Visitor IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.DocumentID, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.invProductID, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Qty, 
                         dbo.saleDocumentDetails.QtyConfirmed, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountPrice, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountUserPrice, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountCost, 
                         dbo.saleDocumentDetails.RespiteDays, dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Date_UpdateLast
```

When I put `select * from TempTable` in this view the above **SSAS generated query** takes 2 minute to run. But when I put **Content Query** in this view SSAS query takes time more than 1 hour!!

I should mention that the time of `biVW_Fact_SaleDocumentDetails` is 6 seconds when it has `select * from TempTable` and its time is 8 seconds when it has **Content Query**.

Answer (score 0):

Since using a view is the 'right' way of creating a DSV for a cube it sounds strange that you have such massive difference in the processing performance (some minor impact is to be expected, but not 3min vs 1h).

You could try and run SQL Server Profiler to see what kind of query is being executed towards the DB during your prolonged cube build, just to make sure it is the same and nothing has gone crazy.

Have you ruled out lack of memory and other physical resources on the server?

As a temp workaround (or permanent solution if you get nowhere trying to find leaking resources) use SSIS to quickly load data into a temp table and then build your cube with that table instead of a view.